# Is it possible to permanently erase information posted in questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, revision-redaction, pii

I came upon a certain Stack Overflow post today, and I was browsing through the edits (because I wanted to find a link to the raw markdown, because it was using snippets strangely and the edit queue was full and I haven't enough rep to edit then and there), and I noticed that the OP accidentally included his email address (from logs) in the post, but edited the question to delete it.  However, it still can be seen in the edit history and anyone can take advantage of that.

<sub>I will reveal the post if needed, but I don't want to draw unnecessary public attention to it if at all possible.</sub>

Comment: It's too late anyway.  The OP should regard that email as unuseable - archive it, open another, update valid sites/services that use it and ask email provider to disable/delete the original.

Comment: Why, because lots of folks have had the change to look at it?

Comment: Yeah - it's probably already on hundreds of spam lists:(